# CakePHP 3.3 confirm deletion of a record using SweetAlert

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp-3.0, sweetalert

I'm using CakePHP 3.3, I have a list of `users` and I want to display a [SweetAlert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/) confirmation box before confirming on canceling the deletion of a specific user.

This is a snippet from `src/Template/Users/index.ctp` file which contains the list of the users :

```
<tbody>
        <?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $this->Html->image('../'.$user->avatar, ['class' => 'img-avatar']); ?></td>
            <td><?= h($user->username) ?></td>
            <td><?= h($user->role) ?></td>
            <td><?= h($user->created) ?></td>
            <td><?= h($user->modified) ?></td>
            <td class="actions">
                <span class="label label-default"><?= $this->Html->link(__('View'), ['action' => 'view', $user->id]) ?></span>
                <span class="label label-default"><?= $this->Html->link(__('Edit'), ['action' => 'edit', $user->id]) ?></span>
                <span class="label label-default"><?= $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), ['action' => 'delete', $user->id], ['confirm' => __('Are you sure you want to delete # {0}?', $user->id)]) ?></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
 </tbody>
 <button class="btn-del">DUMMY BUTTON</button>
```

Then I have a script in my `src/Template/Layout/default.ctp` :

```
<script>
    document.querySelector('.btn-del').onclick = function(){
        swal({
                title: "Are you sure?",
                text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
                type: "warning",
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
                closeOnConfirm: false
            },
            function(){
                swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success");
            });
    };
</script>
```

I tried the script, it's working using the `Dummy Button`, but I have no idea how to make it work so it can confirm or cancel the deletion of a `user` record with a redirection to the `index.ctp` after each deletion.

Sorry I'm a beginner in both CakePHP and JS & Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this by using concepts below:

***HTML***

```
<tr class="home-loan-table">
    <td><?= $this->Html->image($image, array('class' => 'profile-user-img img-responsive img-circle', 'width' => 100, 'height' => 100, 'alt' => 'User profile picture')) ?></td>
    <td><?= $testimonial->has('FromUser') ? $testimonial->FromUser->first_name : $testimonial->name ?></td>
    <td><?= $profile ?></td>
    <td><?= $testimonial->title ?></td>
    <!--<td><?= $testimonial->has('user') ? $this->Html->link($testimonial->user->id, ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'view', $testimonial->user->id]) : '' ?></td>-->
    <td>
        <div class="table-wrap-elps">
            <?= ($testimonial->description) ?>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td><?= $this->Number->format($testimonial->rating) ?></td>
    <td class="actions text-center" style="white-space:nowrap">
        <?= $this->Html->link(__('View'), ['action' => 'view', $testimonial->id], ['class' => 'view-btn']) ?>
        <?= $this->Html->link(__('Edit'), ['action' => 'edit', $testimonial->id], ['class' => 'edit-icon']) ?>
        <?= $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), ['action' => 'delete', $testimonial->id], ['confirm' => __('Confirm to delete this entry?'), 'class' => 'crose-btn hide-postlink']) ?>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="crose-btn postlink-delete">Delete</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

***CSS***

```
<style>
.hide-postlink{
    display: none;
}
.postlink-delete{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

***script***

```
<script>
$(document).on('click', '.postlink-delete', function () {
    var delete_form = $(this).parent().find('form');
    //add sweetalert here then form submit
    delete_form.submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**index.ctp**

```
<?= $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), ['action' => 'delete', $testimonial->id], ['class'=>'your_class','confirm' => __('Confirm to delete this entry?')]) ?>
```

**script**

```
$(".your_class").attr("onclick", "").unbind("click"); //remove function onclick button

$(document).on('click', '.your_class', function () {
    let delete_form = $(this).parent().find('form');
    swal({
        title: "Você tem certeza?",
        text: "Uma vez excluído, você não poderá mais recuperar!",
        icon: "warning",
        buttons: true,
    }).then((willDelete) => {
            if (willDelete) {
                delete_form.submit();
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your code: What does it do, how does it work, and how does it solve OPs problem. Code only answers can lead to [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming), and you risk getting downvotes.